# How to parse JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm pretty new to JSON and jQuery. I have a JSON file from a url and the format is this:

```
{
    "united":[
        {"Atlanta","California","Alabama"}
    ]

    "canada":[
        {"Ontario","British Columbia"},
    ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is when a user selects a country from a list, I would just like to parse out the array specific to the country.

What I have is this so far:

```
function getUrl(country) {
    alert(urlBase + countrylist);
    $.getJSON(urlBase + countrylist, function(data){
       $.each(data, function (index, value) {
           alert(value);
       });
    });
}
```

The alert of value is not being triggered so it doesn't seem to be going inside the each statement.

Comment: This title is misleading. jQuery mobile is a UI framework. jQuery is a javascript library that has helpful utilities that will allow you to parse json $.parseJson()

Comment: thanks for the response.  I'm not getting any error.  trying to figure out if I'm using the getJSON correctly so I can read the list specified by the user.  also I changed the title and I've removed the "mobile" part.  thanks.

Comment: try console.log(data) right underneath $.getJson() tell me what comes up

Comment: Also, is your URL correct? Are you hitting the server?

Comment: neglected to say that the alert of value is not being triggered so it doesn't seem to be going inside the each statement.  thanks again.

Comment: before you call $.each(), put a console.log(data); I need to make sure its not empty.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON appears to not be valid. I think the desired output for the JSON would be:

```
{
    "united":[
        "Atlanta","California","Alabama"
    ], //this comma is new

    "canada":[
        "Ontario","British Columbia" //a comma was removed from here
    ]
}
```

Here is a demo using this structure: http://jsfiddle.net/9sU65/ (watch your console to see it work)

Notice I removed the curly-brackets inside the square-brackets. This now creates a properly formatted array of cities. Also note that a comma had to be placed between the first and second key in the object.

Proper object notation is in this format:

```
{ key1 : 'val-1', key2 : 'val-2' }
```

If you have:

```
{ key1 , key2 }
```

Then you really just want to create an array, which uses slightly different notation:

```
[ key1 , key2 ]
```

BTW, here is the error I get when using your JSON (in Chrome 20):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

There are many out there, but you can always find a JSON validator and see if the JSON is valid. I do this whenever I work with a new data feed, no matter what format the output is in. Here's an example of a good JSON validator: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I believe the trailing comma after British Columbia is syntax error

Comment: By the way, thanks for the responses.  I got things to work out.  The JSON validator helped a lot.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the responses.  I got things to work out.  The JSON validator helped a lot.  Now I have a new question in regards to parsing.  when a user selects a specific state, I have the json data format: '"Georgia: [{name:value,name:value},name:[{name:value,name:value},{name:value,name:value}]]'.  my parsing to select the correct state that is selected works.  but here's my problem now: 'for(var i=0; i<data.Georgia.length; i++) {
   this.name = data.Georgia[i].name;'.  But this is hard coding the state.  how can I do my parsing so that I can parse with variables?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1332427 You will have to create an outer loop, this outer loop cannot be a `for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){...}` loop because it's an associative array (`object`) rather than a standard array. You can use `for (key in data){...}` but that's pretty slow, I'd recommend `$.each(data, function (index, obj) {...});`. Here are docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each